# Edit mode vertices getting dragged?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, vertices, faces, edges

Blender 2.79: I have this problem in edit mode, when I try to move this vertice, it keeps getting dragged away for some reason. I'm trying to create a corrective shape key for this area, the mesh doesn't have any, but with this problem, i can't create it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I can't duplicate the problem. I even opened it in 2.79. Though I did notice that that you're tweaking a mesh that's connected to an armature which is not in its rest pose. Try returning the armature to its rest pose before editing the mesh, and see if that has any effect on your problem.

Comment: I said that i have to create a corrective shape key for that area, so I need the armature to be posed like that. I never had problems with the pose in edit mode, but now this problem appears and i don't know why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem, the issue was that the weight painting of the shoulder and the thorax was intersecting a little bit with the arm weight paint, and caused the vertices to get dragged when posed like that.